Failed to resolve component esp-idf with custom components, how to build the system?
I'm building ESP-IDF project with multiple components (whether custom created or from third-party components in GitHub)
when I tried to combine all together into single project I was not able to compile my projects. I have read the documentation of ESP but even though I could not resolve my issues.
Here is my project structure:
- components
  - cpp_utils
     - CMakeLists.txt
  - LoRa_E22
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - CMakeLists.txt (Yes in components level dir)

- main
  - CMakeLists.txt


Content:

cpp utils is the BT C++ library GitHub link, it requires both CMakeLists file, in components root and in cpp utils. otherwise, it does not compile at all.

cpp_utils/CMakeLists.txt content
# Edit following two lines to set component requirements (see docs)
set(COMPONENT_REQUIRES
     "console"
     "fatfs"
     "json"
     "mdns"
     "nvs_flash"
   )
set(COMPONENT_PRIV_REQUIRES )

file(GLOB COMPONENT_SRCS
     LIST_DIRECTORIES false
     "*.h"
     "*.cpp"
     "*.c"
     "*.S"
    )
set(COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS ".")

register_component()





LoRa E22 is a Lora Ebyte library for receiver and transmitting over Radio based on Lora GitHub

LoRa_E22/CMakeLists.txt content:
set(component_srcs "LoRa_E22.cpp")

idf_component_register(SRCS "${component_srcs}"
                       PRIV_REQUIRES driver
                       INCLUDE_DIRS "."
                       REQUIRES arduino)




Components CMakeList.txt - is empty file

main CMakeLists.txt content:


set(component_srcs "main.cpp" 
                    "src/ble_jobs/ble_app.cpp" 
                    "src/data/models.cpp" 
                    "src/utils.cpp")

idf_component_register(SRCS  "${component_srcs}"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "."
                    REQUIRES "LoRa_E22"
)


all of src/* are my own code, had no issues with it.
Currently the issue is:
Failed to resolve component 'LoRa_E22'.
if I take out the components CMakeList.txt, then cpp_utils fails with undefined issues in esp_bt file and similar.
How can this be resolved ? what am I missing ?

Please, provide the complete error message, like in that question.
